# I'm trying to write a condition for ArrayList .hasNext.. Why can't I write as the following?

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements

The list declaration:

```
private List<SharedData> pairList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and somewhere in the code I'm trying to run a for loop on this List:

```
for(pairList.iterator().hasNext()) {
        do something;
    }
```

but, I receive an error:

```
 Multiple markers at this line

    - Syntax error on tokens, EnhancedForStatementHeaderInit expected 
     instead
    - Syntax error, insert "; ; ) Statement" to complete ForStatement"
```

That's not so clear for me. Why do I need to add ";;"? I'm also not sure it will run correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the while loop - not for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use while loop not for loop because hasNext()returns a boolean.